# Почему не работает код php?

Tags: php

Учусь только программировать на PHP. Когда просто перехожу на главною странице(пример сайт.ru), то оно пишет что это главная, а если переходишь на сайт.ru/index или сайт.ru/photo то просто выбивает ошибка 404..делаю по примеру видео-урока, там все в парня работает.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
$Page = 'index';
$Module = 'index';
} else {
$URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
$Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
$Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);


if (!empty($Module)) {
$Param = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
$Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
}
}
}

if ($Page == 'index') echo 'Главная';
else if ($Page == 'photo') echo 'photo';

?>
```

Файл htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ resource/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный код работает. Проблемы которые могли возникнуть

1. не работает `mod_rewrite` в `apache`. О то что это и как его настроить подробно описано [здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=740)
2. Apache не видит файла `.htaccess`. Ну тут уже крайне много вариантов - поэтому [в гугл за помощью](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=Apache%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20htaccess&es_th=1)

Comment: интересно то что я все делал по видео-уроку, и использовал то же хостинг  что в уроке

Comment: На хостинге может быть отключен `mod_rewrite` и включаться по запросу.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($Page == 'index') include('page/index.php');

function Menu () {
    if $Menu = '<a href="/index">Главная</a>';
    echo '<a href="/">Главная</a>';
}
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку `{}` для выделения кода или отступы в четыре пробела.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?